# EF4: Why isn't Translate() using Table mapping?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, mapping, poco

If I have db table like:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
MyTableId INT PRIMARY KEY,
MyTableName CHAR(10)
)
```

and entity in entity framework 4 (POCO, self tracking) defined as:

```
MyTable - maps to MyTable table
 - Id - maps to MyTableId
 - Name - maps to MyTableName
```

why does this query:

```
SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection)((EntityConnection)context.Connection).StoreConnection;
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable", conn);
DbDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var objResult = context.Translate<MyTable>(result);
```

fail saying:

`The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Project1.MyTable'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.`

Shouldn't the `Translate` method take into account the table mappings defined in edmx? Is there any way to make this work without explicitly defining columns in query?

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384.aspx) says:

> The Translate method enables you to
>   execute a standard ADO.NET query
>   against a data source and translate
>   the returned data rows into entity
>   objects.
>
> The supplied DbDataReader must contain
>   data that maps to the requested entity
>   type.

It isn't explicit whether it maps by name or via the map, but since  this ADO.NET query **isn't** an entity query (and therefore isn't strictly tied to the abstraction layers), it seems *reasonable* that it might ignore it and opt for property-name matches.

I wonder if you should be writing an [ESQL store query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769.aspx), rather than a TSQL database query? I would hope that an ESQL query *is* mapped via the model. This should be *fairly* simple; it could be just

```
var objResult = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<TEntity>(@"select * from MyTable");
```

Comment: I've already tried ExecuteStoreQury<TEntity> and it's not working with the exact same error (I guess it's using Translate internally).